Growth curve analysis advice
I am new to growth curve models and need some guidance. I have data on around 50,000 lambs, each with birth weight and additional measurements taken at two of (approximately) 30, 60, 90, or 120 days after birth, for 3 measurements per lamb. I want to apply growth curve models such as logistic, Gompertz, and von Bertalanffy.
I have some concerns:
Can I perform growth curve analysis using the days and all animal records simultaneously, or do I need to calculate parameters like A and K for individual animals?
If individual calculations are necessary, are three measurements sufficient for each animal?

what do you mean by "two additional measurements taken at approximately 30, 60, 90, and 120 days"? Does that mean that each lamb has birth weight plus two weight measurements at dates that are a subset of {30, 60, 90, 120}? Or that each lamb is weighted twice at each of those 4 subsequent time points? Or that weight and some other characteristic are measured at those 4 time points? Or ... ??

sorry for the confusion. I meant each lamb has birth weight plus two weight measurements at dates that are a subset of {30, 60, 90, 120}. In total, 3 measurements per lamb.

Please add new information as an edit to the post, not only in comments. Comments can be deleted and are often seen by few people

PLoS ONE 12(6): e0178691 has a helpful summary of growth models, with emphasis on Gompertz models. Your problem is that even the simplest growth model needs to estimate 3 parameters: for example the starting value, the ending value, and the slope over time between those values. With only 3 measurements available per lamb you can't get reliable individual growth curves.
You should consider a longitudinal model of weight over time that takes intra-individual correlations into account. Frank Harrell recommends generalized least squares as a way to do growth modeling. That would allow you to model lamb weight as a function of age, using the information from all lambs and the actual ages at weighings, provided that the model is linear in the coefficients associated with age.
The growth models you are interested don't have coefficients linear in age, however. You might perform flexible linear modeling with regression splines (see Chapter 2 of the Harrell reference) with generalized least squares to get an overall shape over time, which you then could approximate with a particular growth model. Alternatively, you could directly use a nonlinear mixed-effects model with your desired nonlinear growth function, with lambs treated as random effects. The R nlme package has an implementation.

This is a good answer, but I think that fitting a full nonlinear mixed model will still be challenging; the question will be which of the coefficients to allow to vary among lambs ("lambs as random effects" is an incomplete specification), and whether they covary with each other. In the maximal model (e.g. Gompertz with scale, location, and asymptote parameters all specified as varying with a 3x3 covariance matrix across lambs), the random effects will be confounded with the residual variance [unless you can fix it/set it to zero]. See https://rpubs.com/bbolker/3423 for a (data-poor) example

@BenBolker thanks for the link. With only ~5 observation times (and only 3 per lamb) I thought that the generalized least squares approach made the most sense, but decided to include the (poorly specified) mixed model as an option. I now see that the problems with a nonlinear mixed model here are even greater than I might have feared.

It would be straightforward to simulate from a best-case scenario (50,000 lambs, randomly sampled observation times from the set, known functional form) and see how much of a challenge this would be in practice (or at least to set a lower bound on the difficulty). Having a large number of clusters (lambs) would mitigate some of the problems at least ...

I have a tentative implementation of this but I'm afraid it might be a little scary ...
